# DynamoDb Put item with a condition check on GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have dynamodb table with GSI as the following:

| ParentId#ChildName |
| --- |
| 2346#John |
| 2388#Jerry |

Now I want to add a new time to the table where parentId = 2388 and ChildName = Tom, before adding this item I want to make sure that the GSI doesn't already contains this combination "2388#Tom".

How can I achieve this, I was thinking of using a condition expression on GSI while doing the putItem operation, but I am not sure if dynamo db support condition expression on secondary indexes?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with the table structure you have. GSIs are eventually consistent and can’t be used in a write, even with transactions.  You can succeed if you manage the GSI propagation yourself to another item or, as this answer mentions, another table.

[DynamoDBSaveExpression with conditional check on GSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093787/dynamodbsaveexpression-with-conditional-check-on-gsi)

Comment: Thanks @hunterhacker for your answer. This approach to propagate data to another table, is it not an anti-pattern?

Comment: It’s not something you do unless it’s the only way. Can you instead change your base table to have that as the PK?

Comment: My base table is already using another attribute as PK which is also necessary as I need to support as lot of update query based on that attribute.  
But I thought of another idea, I think can I use index-overloading on my Primary key here and instead of propagating this data  to a new table, I can just add it as a PK in the same table. So now my PK will be storing multiple type of attributes and I just need to be careful in framing my queries.

Comment: Sure. In my answer I said another item or another table. By saying “another item” I meant within the same table.